# Kafka connect Insert Into field with analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have a field with analyzer simple on elastic.
Also I have a Kafka topic containing AVRO records of the same type (AKA string/text).
First I create an index on elastic of all fields including this analyzer,

INDEX:

```
{
"aliases": {},
"mappings": {
"_default_": {"_all": {"enabled": true}},
"test": { "properties":{ "mUrl": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "simple"}}}
},
"order": 0,
"settings": {"index.mapping.coerce": true, "index.mapping.ignore_malformed": true, "index.number_of_replicas": 0, "index.refresh_interval": "5s"},
"template": "test-*"
}
```

The Avro file is created by kafka-connect (with schema registry) . From sqlserver containing one field mUrl which is nullable nvarchar(500)

Error:

> Mapper for [test] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:
>   [mapper [test] has different [analyzer]]

Comment: Can you provide your existing mapping as well as a sample avro record that you're trying to index?

Comment: just did in the comment above